# setting the vertical axis scale in google charts api

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I was playing around with trying to set the vertical axis scale in my google charts. I'm not happy with the auto scaling that it does since I have two results and want to see them on an even scale for apples-to-apples comparison.

This is my code. I have set the max and min values, yet that does not seem to apply in the output.

Code

```
function createExpenseChart(data) {
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

        var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    chartdata.addColumn('number', 'Expense');
    chartdata.addColumn('number', '2013');
        chartdata.addColumn('number', '2014');

        for (var k in data["Expense"]["2013"]){
            if (data["Expense"]["2013"].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
["2013"][k],10),parseInt(data["Expense"]["2014"][k],10)])
                chartdata.addRow([parseInt(k,10),parseInt(data["Expense"]["2013"][k],10),parseInt(data["Expense"]["2014"][k],10)]);
            }
        }

    var options = {'title':'2013 vs. 2014 comparison,
                curveType: 'function',

viewWindowMode:'explicit',
              viewWindow:{
                max:100000,
                min:10000
        },
        vAxis: {title: 'Cost ($)',
                        minValue: 0,
                },
        hAxis: {title: 'Expense (dollars)'},
        height: 600,
        width: 1000
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('mydiv'));
    chart.draw(chartdata, options);
}
```

I have also tried the following, but they don't show any effect

```
var options = {'title':'2013 v/s 2014',
                curveType: 'function',

viewWindowMode:'explicit',
              viewWindow:{
                max:80,
                min:20
        },
vAxis: {
title: 'Cost ($)'
    viewWindowMode:'explicit',
    viewWindow: {
        max:10000,
        min:10000
    }
},
        hAxis: {title: 'Expense (dollars)'},
        height: 600,
        width: 1000
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, this is resolved. Pretty much the same code worked me. I just had to clean my cache.

Sorry for the confusion.

```
function createExpenseChart(data) {
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packExpenses:["corechart"]});

        var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    chartdata.addColumn('number', 'Expense');
    chartdata.addColumn('number', 'Previous Cost');
        chartdata.addColumn('number', '2014 Cost');

        for (var k in data["Expense"]["2013"]){
            if (data["Expense"]["2013"].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                //console.log([parseInt(k,10),parseInt(data["Expense"]["2013"][k],10),parseInt(data["Expense"]["2014"][k],10)])
                chartdata.addRow([parseInt(k,10),parseInt(data["Expense"]["2013"][k],10),parseInt(data["Expense"]["2014"][k],10)]);
            }
        }

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, pattern: '$###,###'});
    formatter.format(chartdata, 1);
    formatter.format(chartdata, 2);

    var options = {'title':'2013 vs. 2014 Costs by Expense',
                curveType: 'function',
                viewWindowMode:'explicit',
                viewWindow:{
                        min:0
        },
        vAxis: {title: 'Cost ($)',
                viewWindowMode : 'explicit',
                viewWindow:
                {
                        min: 0,
                        max:42000000
                }
                },
        hAxis: {title: 'Expense (years)'},
        height: 600,
        width: 1000
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('Expensecostdiv'));
    chart.draw(chartdata, options);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by 'pretty much' the same?

Comment: @Androbin, well the exact same worked for me, I just had to clean my cache.

Comment: So, if there is no point in this question after all, may you just remove it?